# In R: How to perform log on elements of a matrix without a loop

Tags: r

In R: How do I perform a log operation on every element of a matrix without using a loop?

I have a matrix m and I want each element to be replaced by its log.
log(m) doesn't work.

```
params = array(list(),c(2, 2))
```

then I manually set all elements.

```
params
```

> [,1] [,2]
>
> [1,]   3      3
>
> [2,]   3      3

```
log(params)
```

> Error in log(params) : Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`log(M)` works for all of us on correct matrices:

```
R> M <- matrix(1:4,2)
R> M
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
R> log(M)
        [,1]   [,2]
[1,] 0.00000 1.0986
[2,] 0.69315 1.3863
R>
```

Can you show us your `M` ?

Comment: Your data type is inappropriate.  Create a *numeric* type as *e.g.* in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You failed at making matrix -- this way you have a matrix of lists, and you want a matrix of numbers.
Try this:

```
params<-array(3,c(2,2))
log(params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now assume there is a 0 in some matrix cells.  Furthermore, assume you want a 0 to appear in the output for such cells.

How would you compute the solution now?

Notice that log(0) is not a nice number.